# Exporting offsets from Trimble Rangefinder?

Tags: gps, export, trimble, terrasync

I already asked this question at http://www.rpls.com/forums/viewtopic/8/1276880, but didn't get any answer so far.

We have the following Trimble devices:
[GPS Pathfinder Pro](http://www.trimble.com/pathfinderproxt.shtml), Handheld with [TerraSync](http://www.trimble.com/terrasync.shtml) and a [TruPulse 360b Laser Rangefinder](http://www.lasertech.com/Professional-Measurement-Product-Finder.aspx).

In a (dense) forest, we want to map all trees with 13 hectares (~3000 trees). Some gaps in this forest allow measurements with the dGPS, but mostly there is no reception. By measuring distances, azimuths and slopes between neighboring trees, we could calculate coordinates for all trees, based on the few GPS measurements we take in the gaps.

For this, I can create a feature (without position --> no reception) for each measurement and take an offset measurement from one tree to another with the Rangefinder. I can than export the data file to GPS Pathfinder Office software (V4.2). In the software, I can see the offset for each feature (distance, azimuth, slope) by clicking on it. 
But then there's a problem: In order to use the offset for the calculations, I'd have to export it. In this isn't working. It is possible to export a lot of attributes for each feature, but apparently not the offset.

So here are my questions:

- Is it somehow possible to export the offset measurements with GPS Pathfinder Office (V4.2)?
- If not: Is this possible with the newest version of this software?
- If not: Could any other software accomplish this?

Comment: I think the bug is fixed in GPS Pathfinder Office 5.1 http://trimble.resultspage.com/search?p=Q&ts=custom&w=gps+pathfinder+office+5.1

Comment: @donodarazao, Yes you are right When you export the features the offset information is not in the attibute list, here I have a quesstion when you are entrying the offert the software calculate GPS possition with offset information, so why you need those offsets as a reference in attribute table?

Comment: Exporting offsets would allow the GIS user to see that the accuracy is not what appears in the HPREC and VPREC fields. Offsets are sometimes way off and there is no way to know an offset was applied if it's not exported. I have to resort to putting an Offset = y/n field in the data dictionary of each feature type to capture this.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with this need. I have spoken to a local tech support and they've said that the offset is integrated into the record position. But in Pathfinder you can manually view the offset values. Trimble needs to add the ability to assign the offset values to the exported point record. Without this, their software falls short of being adequate...